# How to properly use href="#someID"?

Tags: jquery, events, html, href

Basically, I want to have a list of links, where each link will show a div. I have everything set up so that this works, but I just have no idea as to which events are getting fired, and in what order. I want to add functionality so that when one of these divs is shown, javascript is run. But so far using code such as this:

`<a href="#div1" onclick="some_script()" />`

calls the some_script() before it actually shows the div. Which is useless to me, since I am trying to get a certain input box to be focused, after showing the div.

Can anyone tell me which jquery events get fired, or and jquery events that I can use so that I can run some_script() after the div is shown to the user?

Comment: First, read more about jQuery basics. There's no need to call `onclick` the way you're doing it.

Comment: Granted, that makes sense. But I also need to do some functions after the div is shown. I would still need to have something with the href, if not just have the onclick instead of the href would I not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){ //attaches click event to all 'a' elements on page
        var div = $(this).attr("href").substr(1); //gets the div
        $(div).show(); //show the div
    });
});
```

This link should get you started with jQuery. http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: I kinda thought that I was going to have to do something like this. Now I don't want to attach this to all 'a' elements, before I go to into testing here, $('.divClass').click ... should only give me elements with the divClass class right? is there anyway to only select 'a' elements with the divClass element?

dumb thing to ask aswell, but can I pass the 'this' element throught javascript if I wanted to have the function on a separate file?

Comment: Yes `$('.divClass')` would only select elements with that class. You can put this function in a separate js file as long as it is reference in your page, and the function(s) are wrapped in `$(document).ready({})`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirements correctly:

**HTML**

```
<p><a href="#div_one" class="trigger">1st div</a></p>
<p><a href="#div_two" class="trigger">2nd div</a></p>
<div id="div_one">
    Some content
    <input type="text" name="input1" class="input">
</div>
<div id="div_two">
    Some more content
     <input type="text" name="input2" class="input">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    border: 2px solid green;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: black;
    display: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target_div = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target_div).toggle();
    $(target_div).find('.input').focus();
});
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/byuPL/